# Flutter pdf to ppt convertor

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

Is there any way to directly convert pdf file to ppt in flutter?
Anybody can suggest me some package for this

I have searched for such package but I haven't got anyone

Answer (score 0):

You could go with this 2 ways:

1. **Directly PPT Conversion**: You could give this **[power_file_view](https://pub.dev/packages/power_file_view)** package a check where you could pass in a pdf from the app or from the network as a **parameter** in it and then **convert** it to ppt.
2. **Convert File to PDF then PPT**: Check out the **[syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^20.4.49](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf)** in this, you could create PDF Files and then Convert it to PPT using **above** Package.

Choose any approaches that suit your need :)